# Bulk update set of URLs via SQL

Tags: permalinks, sql

I've checked multiple questions and can't seem to find the answer.

How can I update a list of URLs to either include "-google" at the end of the permalink, or set the URL to a custom url. My list of URLs is 100+ and I have what the URL is and what the URL should be.

**For example:**

```
https://examplesite.com/customer/customer-name
```

*change to:*

```
https://examplesite.com/customer/google-customer-name
```

**I have already updated the URLs in the post_content using this below:**

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'https://examplesite.com/customer/customer-name','https://examplesite.com/customer/google-customer-name');
```

That worked for the post content, but it's not a solution to update the permalink of those pages, which is what I need.

Comment: OK, so what exactly are you trying to do? I understand that you want to change URLs of posts, but then you're saying, that you tried to replace them in post_content... I'm a little bit confused :(

Comment: I know someone would suggest the SQL I already used to update the URLs in the content. What I need to do now is update my list of URLs with new URLs that I already have setup. I'm trying to do this without having to manually go to 100+ pages/posts to update their permalink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so let's assume you have these URLs in some array (if you don't, you can easily prepare it using any developer text editor, I guess). Let's call that array `$slugs` and let's say it's defined like so:

```
$slugs = array(
    'customer-name' => 'google-customer-name',
    ...
);
```

So there are only slugs in there.

So now you'll have to modify the posts:

```
global $wpdb;
foreach ( $slugs as $old => $new ) {
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->posts,
        array( 'post_name' => $new ),
        array( 'post_name' => $old )
    );
}
```

This will change the slugs, hence the permalinks, for these posts.

Comment: This looks good, but before I run this code, I only need to run it once and then I can delete it after. How should I run this PHP once and have the changes be permanent?

Comment: Yes, you have to run it only once. There are many ways to run it, I guess... I add it in themes functions.php and wrap it with `if ( isset($_GET['domystuff']) ) {  ... here comes the code }` then I just go to the page and add `?domystuff=1` to the URL. It's not pretty, but it's pretty quick way to run some code manually...

Comment: Alright, I was able to test this out and it doesn't seem to be working. Here is a small sample of the code:

`<?php
if ( isset($_GET['googlify']) ) { 
    $slugs = array(
        '/customer-stories/madhive' => '/customer-stories/google-madhive',
        '/customer-stories/digital-first-media' => '/customer-stories/google-digital-first-media'
    );
    global $wpdb;
    foreach ( $slugs as $old => $new ) {
        $wpdb->update(
            $wpdb->posts,
            array( 'post_name' => $new ),
            array( 'post_name' => $old )
        );
    }
 }
?>`

Comment: Of course your code won't work. But the problem is not with the code, but with your slugs array. Take a look at my code and on your code. What do slugs look like in my code and what do they look in your code? See any difference? ;) There should be no slashes in slugs. Also slug is only the last part of URL, not all of the URL.

Comment: Well how can I keep that same structure. It's using a custom slugs plugin and the slug for instance, for the first one, is /customer-stories/madhive. The /customer-stories/ is part of it..it's even stored like that in the database.

Comment: You have to use the same slugs that already are in database. I have no idea how your site is constructed and what the slugs really are. By default in WP slug is only the last part of URL and it should not contain any slashes. If your slugs contain some slashes, then use them...

Comment: I included the slashes, as you saw, and it's not replacing it correctly. I tried removing the first part and just having the last part of the slug and it's not working either. What would you need to see from me in order to know how the slug should be setup?

Comment: @radethdart it's not about guessing what you want to replace, but about checking it. You want to replace something with something - so go to your database and check what the `post_name` field contains... This is what you have to replace.

Comment: Your code actually worked beautifully! It's the custom permalink plugin that has everything all messed up and not working with the default changes. Thank you so much for helping out with this, and being so responsive! I will mark this as the answer as it worked in the end.

Comment: @radethdart I’m glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

For permalinks have you tried to reset your permalink settings through admin panel? e.g. in *Settings* > *Permalinks* switch from **Post name** to **Numeric** and then back to **Post name**.

Comment: I'm not wanting to change ALL the urls, just a list of URLs that I have in a spreadsheet.